# Combine multiple formulas

Tags: excel, syntax, nested

I need to be able to calculate results in an Excel spreadsheet and have written 5 separate formulas to cover the possible number of selections. In short, the technique is known as Dutching, whereby if any of the selections in a group of rows wins, the profit is the same.

To identify the groups, Column E has a COUNTIFS formula which compares the date and time in Columns A & B and puts a count of how many match. The results of the count range from 1 through to 5. That is all fine; anything with 1 is a single selection in an event; if it is 2, 3, 4 & 5, this means groups of selections running in the same event. I have now written 5 separate formulas which can calculate the profit of each group, the problem is that the calculations need to be pasted to the first row of the correct group to achieve the desired result. Since there over 10,000 rows, this is really cumbersome and I would prefer to have one formula created out of the 5. This formula would naturally need to identify the groups and apply the formula to just the first row of the group.

So basically, IF E2=1, then run calculation 1; IF E2=2 then run calculation 2; IF E2=3 run 3 and so on.

Here are the 5 separate formulas, all of which work on their own:-

**For a single selection**

```
=IF(V2="W",98*T2-98,-100)
```

**For a group of 2 rows**

```
=IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3)*98)*T2)-98,-100)
```

**For a group of 3 rows**

```
=IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3+1/T4)*98)*T2)-98,-100)
```

**For a group of 4 rows**

```
=IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W”,V5=“W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5)*98)*T2)-98,-100)
```

**For a group of 5 rows**

```
=IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4=“W”,V5=“W",v6="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5+1/T6)*98)*T2)-98,-100)
```

So if any of the formulas are run on a cell which is NOT in the first row of the group, it naturally fails to calculate correctly, as it counts down from the top, so I really need the IF(OR statements to be nested and have something forcing it to only calculate on the first row of each group.

I have tried for ages to put them together, but am struggling miserably, so am hoping someone here has a more advanced understanding of nesting and the important thing of forcing the calculation to only be performed on the first row in the group.

Thanks so much in advance.

[image: Spreadsheet Image]

[image: Spreadsheet Image]

---

Update (this is what I had tried so far) :

```
=IF(OR(E1<>E2,E2=1,(ROW()>3)*(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1)="")*(E2=2),(ROW()>4)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E2=3),(ROW()>5)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-3,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E2=4),(ROW()>6)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(INDIRECT("H"&ROW()-4),""),IFERROR(INDIRECT("H"&ROW()-3),""),IFERROR(INDIRECT("H"&ROW()-2),""),INDIRECT("H"&ROW()-1))="")*(E2=5)),IF(E2=1,IF(V2="W",98*T2-98,-100),IF(E2=2,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W"),(((1/T2)/(1/T2+1/T3)*98)*T2)-98,-100),IF(E2=3,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W"),(((1/T2)/(1/T2+1/T3+1/T4)*98)*T2)-98,-100),IF(E2=4,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W",V5="W"),(((1/T2)/(1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5)*98)*T2)-98,-100),IF(E2=5,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W",V5="W",v6="W"),(((1/T2)/(1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5+1/T6)*98)*T2)-98,-100),IF(E2=6,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W",V5="W”,V6=“W”, V7=“W"),(((1/T2)/(1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5+1/T6+1/T7)*98)*T2)-98,-100),""))))),"")
```

@p-phidot I have started out trying to create the [RunMe] part of the formula before trying the other part. I am doing this is another sheet which has different cell references, though that shouldn't be an issue. I have also decided not to have the formula check for anything which is 1, only 2, 3, 4, 5 & 6. The aim of this was always to check for profit for Dutching, which really means using more than 1 selections, so have just decided to eliminated 1 from the equation.

Here is what I put together, though just as a straight formula, it gives no result when pasted into a cell in Row 2

```
=IF(E2=2,IF(OR(K2="W",K3="W"),(((1/I2) / (1/I2+1/I3)*98)*I2)-98,-100) ,IF(E2=3,IF(OR(K2="W",K3="W",K4="W"),(((1/I2) / (1/I2+1/I3+1/I4)*98)*I2)-98,-100) ,IF(E2=4,IF(OR(K2="W",K3="W",K4="W",K5="W"),(((1/I2) / (1/I2+1/I3+1/I4+1/I5)*98)*I2)-98,-100) ,IF(E2=5,IF(OR(K2="W",K3="W",K4="W",K5="W",K6="W"),(((1/I2) / (1/I2+1/I3+1/I4+1/I5+1/I6)*98)*I2)-98,-100)) ,IF(E2=6,IF(OR(K2="W",K3="W",K4="W",K5="W",K6="W",K7="W"),(((1/I2) / (1/I2+1/I3+1/I4+1/I5+1/I6+1/I7)*98)*I2)-98,-100)  ,  ""  )))))
```

Does anything look amiss with this at all?

cheers

Comment: I found something that won't make your equation 4 & 5 works, it's the " symbol.. wrongly typed (here, in question) as ” & “. It should be " .

Answer (score 0):

Although you could certainly nest the IF's, which might be more understandable, try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(V2:INDEX(V2:V6,E1),"W")=E1,1/SUM(1/T2:INDEX(T2:T6,E1))*98-98,-100)
```

The formula creates dynamic ranges for which to both check against `E1` and also to create your formula (simplified a bit by factoring out some extraneous factors).

The general nesting format is something like:

```
=if(e1=1,formula1,
    if(e1=2, formula2, …
```

Your formulas start with a count of "W" in the range of `V2:V6` that should be matching the value in `E1`, so we can use that in constructing our dynamic ranges.

**EDIT:**

After you clarified your problem with data, and expected results, I developed the following solution.

I turned your input into a **Table** and used structured references so as to clarify better than trying to use dynamic range references.

I am also using the `OFFSET` function but, if speed becomes an issue, we may want to change that to a non-volatile `INDEX` function, but I won't have time this morning.

Some of the results are off slightly from what you show.  I assume that is due to rounding in your real data.

The formula logic is the same as my first, with changes in the logic to tell when to output any data at all, vs outputting the calculation or the `-100`.

The formula (assuming the table starts in A1):

```
=IF(OR(Table1[@[Date]:[Time]]<>A1:B1),IF(OR(OFFSET([@Result],0,0,[@Occurrences])="W"),1/SUM(1/OFFSET([@BSP],0,0,[@Occurrences]))*98-98,-100),"")
```

If the table does not start in `A1`, change the term `A1:B1` to reflect the `Date` and `Time` column header cells of your real data. (May need a different term if the `Date/Time` cells are not adjacent). And be sure to use the `A1` reference style and **NOT** a reference to the `[#Header]` row, since we need this reference to adjust to always refer to the row above as the formula fills down.

**EDIT2:** If calculation speed is slow and you want to avoid using the volatile `OFFSET` function, the following makes use of the `INDEX` function to create our dynamic ranges, and is non-volatile, so should be faster:

```
=IF(OR(Table1[@[Date]:[Time]]<>A1:B1),
    IF(OR((([@Result]):INDEX([Result],ROW()-1-ROW(Table1[#Headers])+[@Occurrences]))="W"),
       1/SUM(1/(([@BSP]):INDEX([BSP],ROW()-1-ROW(Table1[#Headers])+[@Occurrences])))*98-98,-100),
          "")
```

#### Table with Dutching Results

[image]

Comment: cheers Ron. Unfortunately that initial formula gives the correct results for single row groups, but all groups of multiple rows show as -100, even those with a W in column E. The result of -100 is also in each cell of the group, rather than being just in the first cell (or even the row with the "W"). So if it is a group of 4 rows, each row shows as -100, rather than that result just showing in the first cell of that group.
It must be close, though, as the calculation is correct for single rows.

Comment: @honkin Then just use the second, nesting method. Or edit your question to provide an example if what you really need. Perhaps you are not properly using the formula, as it works based on the formulas you provided.

Comment: The second method completely ignores identifying the groups of rows, so for 10,000+ rows, it is simply not feasible, as it would mean manually pasting the correct formula into the 1st row of each group. Your formula does not seem to calculate anything except a single row. I have just run each formula against each group of rows, manually pasting them into the first row of each group. All worked as they should, though as with anything copied either to or from groups like this, some of "W" become "W” so I had to fix the ". Other than that, they all work fine. I will paste a working sample

Comment: Hi Ron
So I have just added a screen grab of one of the working sheets. It shows the results with 2, 3 & 4 rows per group. I didn't bother with the single rows, as they were working fine. I added these formulas manually to the first row of each group, as it does not calculate correctly if it is pasted into any other row. This is the reason why this method is so cumbersome, as it is labour-intensive.
When your formula was pasted in the next column, ALL results were -100, so something is just not quite right. Sheets have a header row.

Comment: Oh, just so you know, with this particular sheet, number of rows is still in E, but the W or L is now in K and the price calculation is done from I. As I said, I pasted your formula in the column beside Dutching...made sure the column and row references were correct and pasted it down the column. All results were -100.
cheers

Comment: @honkin yep, that's what happens when you provide insufficient information about your real situation. I'll take a look later today.

Comment: The large spreadsheet that this is intended for already has a table created (Table1...same as yours), but when I copy and paste your formula into BT2 #VALUE! is the result. Could it be the OFFSET function not addressing the correct location of either W and/or the Occurrences? The columns I supplied as a screen grab had many columns hidden to get to that point and many remain hidden generally. Label for BSP is in T1 in this sheet and is labelled BSP. Occurrences is E1, yet the result is #VALUE! in all cells. Date is A1 Time is B1 Result is BS1

Comment: @honkin *Could it be the OFFSET function ...*?  Unlikely. The only non structured addresses in the formula are `A1:B1`, and I gave you specific instructions about that. Did you follow them?  And, as you can see from the screen shot, the formula works on the data you have provided.  Most likely, you data is something other than what you have represented; although a `#VALUE!` error can be hard to run down, sometimes.

Comment: @honkin Another possibility is a `ERROR` in your data someplace.

Comment: The difference with the data you used is you typed the numbers under Occurrences and typed W, L or P into the cells. In the working spreadsheet, those are generated by formulas. I'm not sure if that makes a difference. I have just uploaded a screenshot of the working spreadsheet. As I indicated, many rows are hidden from view as they are not relevant to the results. I changed the label of Occurrences to Selections and altered the formula to reflect it.

Comment: @honkin Please explain why you think the values being generated by formulas, vs being typed in, make a difference?  As I wrote above, it can certainly make a difference in the values being returned in the `Dutching` column, but I don't understand why you think it should generate `#VALUE!` errors, unless your formulas are not generating real numbers.  Possibly you didn't alter the formula properly when you edited it?

Comment: The numbers in BSP are input manually, so no possible errors there...they are just numbers. Date & Time can't possibly have errors and the only other 2 columns addressed are Selections (Occurrences) and Results, both of which are generated by formulas. Could it have anything to do with so many rows being hidden? Clutching at straws, I know, but can't for the life of me see why it works in your example, yet not in the working sheet. Thanks again

Comment: @honkin If you thought hidden rows (or columns) might be the problem, what happened when you unhid them?

Comment: @honkin If your **Table** range does not encompass the entire table of data, you can get `#VALUE!` errors.  Check the table name to be sure its range includes your entire data range

Comment: @honkin Another option would be to replace the structured references with regular range references, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your effort. Unfortunately, none of the options worked on the working spreadsheet, but another contributor has supplied me with a working solution which is perfect. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just add another if.. that should do :

```
=IF(E2=1,IF(V2="W",98*T2-98,-100)
,IF(E2=2,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3)*98)*T2)-98,-100)
,IF(E2=3,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3+1/T4)*98)*T2)-98,-100)
,IF(E2=4,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W",V5="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5)*98)*T2)-98,-100)
,IF(E2=5,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W",V5="W",v6="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5+1/T6)*98)*T2)-98,-100)

,  ""  )))))
```

or combined (same formula.. just in 1 line):

```
=IF(E2=1,IF(V2="W",98*T2-98,-100) ,IF(E2=2,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3)*98)*T2)-98,-100) ,IF(E2=3,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3+1/T4)*98)*T2)-98,-100) ,IF(E2=4,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W",V5="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5)*98)*T2)-98,-100) ,IF(E2=5,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W",V5="W",v6="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5+1/T6)*98)*T2)-98,-100)  ,  ""  )))))
```

---

**UPDATE :**

Taking the above equation as [ExecutionFormula]. Wrap the above equation in this :

```
=IF(

    OR(
        E1<>E2,
        E2=1,
        (ROW()>3)*(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1)="")*(E2=2),
        (ROW()>4)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E2=3),
        (ROW()>5)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-3,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E2=4),
        (ROW()>6)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-4,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-3,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E2=5)

    ),

    [ExecutionFormula]

    ,"")
```

Or in one line :

```
=IF(OR( E1<>E2, E2=1, (ROW()>3)*(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1)="")*(E2=2), (ROW()>4)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E2=3), (ROW()>5)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-3,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E2=4), (ROW()>6)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-4,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-3,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E2=5)),IF(E2=1,IF(V2="W",98*T2-98,-100),IF(E2=2,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W"),(((1/T2)/(1/T2+1/T3)*98)*T2)-98,-100),IF(E2=3,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W"),(((1/T2)/(1/T2+1/T3+1/T4)*98)*T2)-98,-100),IF(E2=4,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W",V5="W"),(((1/T2)/(1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5)*98)*T2)-98,-100),IF(E2=5,IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4="W",V5="W",v6="W"),(((1/T2)/(1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5+1/T6)*98)*T2)-98,-100),""))))),"")
```

Idea : use column() n row() to check current cell address and use as offset. upon checking blank vs E2 value, determine whether should blank or do calculation.

---

**UPDATE 2 :**

> Does E26 look right to you?

Congratulations.. it's a very close try, but sorry.. that's not it. I'll try to explain how this thing works while guiding how to edit it. Edit the code is easy, but in the long run.. understanding is a need (to troubleshoot/expand it later). I'll start with the easy one, edit code.

So far we had seen the BIG picture, the formula is :

```
=if ( or(...),  [ExecutionFormula]  , ""  )
```

So there is 2 part One is the `...` , another is `[ExecutionFormula]` . But I want to call them with another name (for undestanding sake). So `...` is `[ChkEmptyCell]`, and `[ExecutionFormula]` is now `[RunMe]`. With that, the new structure is :

```
= if ( [ChkEmptyCell] is true , [RunMe] , else "" )
```

With the renaming done.. and since this formula is quite loooong, we need a tool to help us do the bracket tracing. I use notepad++, but you may also use https://pastebin.to/, up to you, but with some tool the missing/extra bracket wont be a major problem later.

Now, we look at the `[RunMe]` code. We do aware if() is a 3 parts function, so just break them down clearly..  Copy the 1st formula above and paste it in the tool of your choice, until you get the braekdown of EVERY if() inside it. the basic structure for `[RunMe]` is :

```
=IF ( E2=1 , <Do A> , IF ( E2=2 , <Do B> , "" ) )
```

So to expand it.. It'll be

```
=IF ( E2=1 , <Do A> , IF ( E2=2 , <Do B> , IF ( E2=3 , <Do C> , IF ( E2=4 , <Do D> , IF ( E2=5 , <Do E> , IF ( E2=6 , <Do F> , "" ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Done - for the `[RunMe]` part.

Next, the `[ChkEmptyCell]`. We start with the purpose 1st.

The `[ChkEmptyCell]` is created check how many empty cell is above the current cell. If the number of empty cell is OK, then only do `[RunMe]`, else give a blank.

The structure of `[ChkEmptyCell]` is :

```
OR( <condition1>, <condition2>, <condition3>, <condition4>, <condition5>, <condition6> )
```

I use E10 instead of E2, for easier example. with :

```
condition1 :
    If ( E9 <> E10, [RunMe], "")
condition2 :
    If ( E10 is 1, [RunMe], "")
condition3 :
    If ( E10 is 2, AND E10 = E9 AND 1 cell above the current cell is empty, [RunMe], else "" ) 
condition4 :
    If ( E10 is 3, AND E10 = E9 AND E9 = E8 AND the 2 cells above the current cell is empty, [RunMe], else "" )
condition5 :
    If ( E10 is 4, AND E10 = E9 AND E9 = E8 AND E8 = E7 AND the 3 cells above the current cell is empty, [RunMe], else "" )
condition6 :
    If ( E10 is 5, AND E10 = E9 AND E9 = E8 AND E8 = E7 AND E7 = E6 AND the 4 cells above the current cell is empty, [RunMe], else "" )
```

As you can see, for condition4 to condition6, it will result an error if evaluated in E2 cells. That's why we have `(ROW()>3)` & `IFERROR( ... , "")` in the logic. It is meant to 'handle' the special condition in the first few row.

As for the `OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1),COLUMN()-1)`, it is used to define the current cell location.

So `OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1)` is one cell above the current cell, `OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1)` is 2 cells above the current cell, and so on.

That's why to check "1 cell above the current cell is empty" (condition3) , we don't need concatenate. but when we want to do "2 cells above the current cell is empty" (condition4), we need `concatenate (cell1,cell2)`.

So in condition3, to check "3 cells above the current cell is empty", we do `concatenate (cell1,cell2,cell3)`, and so on.

Hope by this part you can see how the whole thing works. And having some idea to 'edit' & combine the `[ChkEmptyCell]` & create the `[Runme]` formula. with E2=6 condition it's structure should be some thing like :

```
 =IF(  

    OR( <condition1>,<condition2>,<condition3>,<condition4>,<condition5>,<condition6>,<condition7> ) 

    ,IF ( E2=1, <Do A>, IF ( E2=2, <Do B>, IF ( E2=3, <Do C>, IF ( E2=4, <Do D>, IF ( E2=5, <Do E>, IF ( E2=6, <Do F>, "" )))))) 

    , "" 

    )
```

I'll share the answer for E2=6,  IF you edit the question and include E2=6 as on of the official question (not in comment).

Hope it clears some air.. ( :

---

**UPDATE 3 :**

AFAIK, you are on track. You are stuck at the place where I expect you to stuck at. d:

Congratulations for the understanding effort. Really appreciate it. Keep it up. ( :

Based on "The aim of this was always to check for profit for Dutching" statement..  I assume that the formula is applied in BT column. I'll also assume that the formula is applied in BT10 cell.

So the resultant formula @ BT10 is :

```
=IF(
    OR( 

        E9<>E10, 

        E10=1, 

        (ROW()>3)*(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1)="")*(E10=2),

        (ROW()>4)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E10=3),
        (ROW()>5)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-3,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E10=4),
        (ROW()>6)*(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-4,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-3,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="")*(E10=5)
    )

    ,IF(E10=1,IF(V10="W",98*T10-98,-100),IF(E10=2,IF(OR(V10="W",V11="W"),(((1/T10)/(1/T10+1/T11)*98)*T10)-98,-100),IF(E10=3,IF(OR(V10="W",V11="W",V12="W"),(((1/T10)/(1/T10+1/T11+1/T12)*98)*T10)-98,-100),IF(E10=4,IF(OR(V10="W",V11="W",V12="W",V13="W"),(((1/T10)/(1/T10+1/T11+1/T12+1/T13)*98)*T10)-98,-100),IF(E10=5,IF(OR(V10="W",V11="W",V12="W",V13="W",V14="W"),(((1/T10)/(1/T10+1/T11+1/T12+1/T13+1/T14)*98)*T10)-98,-100),"")))))

    ,""

    )
```

"I cannot get my head around the concept of the [CheckEmptyCell]" The [CheckEmptyCell] is quite an advanced concept inside another. It took me few days of trial.. So I don't really remember how many formula that I've tested and how it failed. Having that as a disclaimer, forgive me if I'm going too low (on the knowledge part), here is the breakdown.

Here's all three "concepts".

***One : [ getting the current cell location ]***

```
OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1)
```

The current cell location (using the above assumption) is BT10. but how to write `If(BT9="",DoA,DoB)` WITHOUT knowing where the formula will be applied? Use combination of offset row & column function.

Since A1 cell have the value of ROW() = 1 & COLUMN() = 1 . So BT10 will have ROW() = 10 & COLUMN() = 72 . So if we want to refer to BT10, we do OFFSET($A$1,(10-1),(72-1)). Done. Thus `If(BT10="",DoA,DoB)` can be written as `If(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1),COLUMN()-1) ="",DoA,DoB)` .

Notice the missing "-1" ? It is used to refer to 1 cell above BT10 which is.. BT9 so `If(BT9="",DoA,DoB)` is written as `If(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1)="",DoA,DoB)` .

To refer to 2 cells above (BT8), we add another row offset. And so on. ( You had notice this offset increment pattern in the condition3 vs condition4 condition5 ++ )

By now you should notice that.. why I use this complicated referencing while I can just achieve the same thing by manually entering "BT9" or "BT8" in the formula and drag it up/downwards? The problem shows up when we apply this formula to BT2, and it 'want' to check 2 cells above it. Since the cell is not there, this will results error for the 1st few lines.

End of part One.

***Two : [ Why the OR() look so weird? ]***

The [CheckEmptyCell] equation is structured as :

```
OR( <condition1>, <condition2>, <condition3>, <condition4>, <condition5>, <condition6> )
```

Condition1 & 2 is the easiest to get.

- condition1 [`E9<>E10`] :  Means, if the current row E values and the previous row is different, give it a TRUE. >> So [RunMe].
- condition2 [`E10=1`] :  If the the current row E value is 1, give it a TRUE. >> So [RunMe].

If the one of the above 2 conditions are fulfilled, then the [Runme] statement will be run. OK. What if the value is 2 and it is repeated (in E9 & E10) ? and what if 2 is repeated more that twice ?

- condition3 [ `(ROW()>3) * (OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1)="") * (E10=2)` ] :  there is 3 terms here `(term1)*(term2)*(term3)` .

"..if the value is 2 and it is repeated (in E9 & E10) ?  " > condition1 is FALSE, so does condition2.

There is 2 things to be taken note here. One is that if the current row '2' (in E10) is the second '2' appearing (after E9).. then the current row should be empty.

Second is (refers to "..if 2 is repeated more that twice ? " ), if E8 value is also '2', then the current row MUST do [Runme], it cannot be empty.

To make this happen, we just check if the cell (BT9) above the current cell (BT10) is empty, or not using "term2". If it is empty, return a TRUE ([RunMe]), else a FALSE (empty). ///\\

"term3" is straightforward to get. But why "term1" ?

"term1" is to say that... this (condition3) check will only to be done on the 4th row and above, no such "empty cell check" is to be done for the 1st 3 rows.

"*term4*" ?!!  it was not explicitly defined here but term4 indirectly refers to [E9=E10]. Technically, condition3 evaluation is only valid if E9=E10. In another way, in OR(A,B,C) , C evaluation is only of some value only when A & B is FALSE. This is some of the basic logic manipulation learnt from the "Digital Electronics" subject lecture.

Refer to the marked ///\\ sentence.. somehow, it (term4) does :

(1) If the BT9 is not empty, then indirectly [ E9 = E10 ] & [ E9 = 2 & E10 = 2 ] is verified. & it returns blank (FALSE).

(2) If the BT9 is empty, then indirectly [ E8 = E9 = E10 ] & [ E10 = '2'] is verified. & it returns [RunMe] (TRUE).

As I said.. both are not explicitly typed in the equation, but BOTH term4 evaluations MUST be done for the "E10=2 [RunMe] logic" to work for all cases (Eg. single/double/triple appearance of '2' in columnE).

OK. End of condition3.

Next.

- condition4 [ `(ROW()>4) * (CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="") * (E10=3)` ] :  there is 4 terms here `(term1)*(concatenate((term2a),(term2b))*(term3)` .

"term1", clarification is similar to above. This (condition4) check will only to be done on the 5th row and above, no such "empty cell check" is to be done for the 1st 4 rows.

"term3", means this check only valid for E10 = 3.

The concatenate() is to cater for " what if 3 is repeated more that three times ? " condition. So for '3'.. using "concept One", we now know that : term2a refers to BT8 & term2b _ BT9 .

We just check if the 2 cells (BT8 & BT9) above the current cell (BT10) is empty or not, using (concatenate((term2a),(term2b)) . Where term2a refers to BT8/2 cell above) & term2b refers to BT9/1 cell above.
If both are empty, return a TRUE ([RunMe]), if only one cell (BT9) is empty OR both cells (BT8 & BT9) have value, return a FALSE (empty). The "term2a" is warped in iferror(,"") coz it will be error when entered into BT2 (row2), where the reference cell does not exist. ////\\

"term4" applies here too. Refer to the marked ////\\ sentence.. For 2 "Empty" cells (in BT9 & BT8) to happen, BT7 MUST have the value for [RunMe]. Thus, E7, E8 & E9 values MUST be 3. Indirectly, for E10 = 3 :

(1) If BT9 is not blank, blank the current cell. (FALSE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=3 ]

(2) If BT9 is blank & BT8 is not blank, blank the current cell. (FALSE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=E8=3 ]

(3) If BT9 & BT8 is blank, do [RunMe] (TRUE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=E8=E7=3 ]

It can't be taken for granted that "term4" plays quite a role here. You can see that ALL the evaluations above MUST be done for the "E10=3 [RunMe] logic" to work for all cases. ( :

End of condition4 story/concept.

- condition5 [ `(ROW()>5) * (CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-3,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="") * (E10=4)` ] :  or `(term1)*(concatenate((term2a),(term2b),(term2c))*(term3)` .

Where term2a refers to BT7, term2b _ BT8 & term2c _ BT9.

So for condition5 (E10=4), the term4 sounds like this :

(1) If BT9 is not blank, blank the current cell. (FALSE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=4 ]

(2) If BT9 is blank & BT8 is not blank, blank the current cell. (FALSE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=E8=4 ]

(3) If BT9 & BT8 is blank & BT7 is not blank, blank the current cell. (FALSE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=E8=E7=4 ]

(4) If BT9 & BT8 & BT7 is blank, do [RunMe] (TRUE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=E8=E7=E6=4 ]

- condition6 [ `(ROW()>6) * (CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-4,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-3,COLUMN()-1),""),IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-2,COLUMN()-1),""),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-1,COLUMN()-1))="") * (E10=5)` ] :  or `(term1)*(concatenate((term2a),(term2b),(term2c),(term2d))*(term3)` .

Where term2a refers to BT6, term2b _ BT7, term2c _ BT8 & term2d _ BT9 .

For condition6 (E10=5), the term4 sounds like this :

(1) If BT9 is not blank, blank the current cell. (FALSE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=5 ]

(2) If BT9 is blank & BT8 is not blank, blank the current cell. (FALSE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=E8=5 ]

(3) If BT9 & BT8 is blank & BT7 is not blank, blank the current cell. (FALSE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=E8=E7=5 ]

(4) If BT9 & BT8 & BT7 is blank & BT6 is not blank, blank the current cell. (FALSE) Also verified :  [ E10=E9=E8=E7=E6=5 ]

(5) If BT9 & BT8 & BT7 & BT6 is blank, do [RunMe] (TRUE) Also verified : [ E10=E9=E8=E7=E6=E5=5 ]

End of part Two.

***Three : [ The whole adventure & beyond ]***

By far, this the 1st time I've spent so much time testing out the cases, but end up with a much shorter code than expected. As you can see above, the 'invisible' term4 is actually consist of so many rules, and we need ALL of it. Ironically, it was executed by NOT defining it directly (this is the logic manipulation part - keyword:Boolean Algebra). Thanks for this question, it has been quite a revision to myself.

Beyond - for E10=6, expand condition6 to `(term1)*(concatenate((term2a),(term2b),(term2c),(term2d),(term2e))*(term3)` and add it to the OR() term in [CheckEmptyCell].

Put the tried formula by editing (add it in) your question. I'll be happy to have a look/check. ( :

---

**UPDATE 4 :**

I felt a bit tough not to use the above text (without code line numbers) for explanation. Here I'll present you with the simplified explanation (with line numbers). also the FULL solution with "E2=6".

Here, I use the line numbers for each section. You may open both code side by side for better comparison.

Here is the structure for the overall original code : https://pastebin.com/yyv0xswq

And here is the full code : https://pastebin.com/gqjjhbV4

Note that line 4 to 28 (in the full code) is "condition1-condition6" & line 32 to 61 is "action A to E" in the above code (I'm refering to the line numbers in the pastebin).

Compare that to the structure for the overall additional (E2=6) code : https://pastebin.com/SUu5i4aJ

And is its full code is : https://pastebin.com/EEdSgsZu

Where that line 4 to 36 is (in the full code) "condition1-condition7" (note that there is an extra term with "-5" in the concatenate of condition7) & line 41 to 74 is "action A to F" in the above code (I'm refering to the line numbers in the pastebin).

Pls test the solution and if it works/not. ( :

Comment: cheers and thanks for your reply @p._phidot. No, this puts a result in every cell, so it fails to address the key issue here of the groups of rows. Each group requires just a single result; there are groups of 1, 2, 3, 4 & 5 rows and the result is to go just in the top row of each group.
Thanks for the effort

Comment: Ok. noted. But is the values generated (at the desired location @ top row of each group) correct ?

Comment: BTW, have a try on the updated solution. I really hope that this helps.

Comment: @p_phidot That is absolutely perfect. It does all the calculations on the first row of each group of rows. In pasting it all in, I noticed amongst the 10000+ rows that there were 2 groups of 6 rows; I had not noticed them before. So this formula is 99% correct, but missing the final part; a calculation for when their is a group of 6. It is the same as the others, with just a small addition for 6 rows.
=IF(OR(V2="W",V3="W",V4=“W”,V5=“W",V6="W", V7="W"),(((1/T2) / (1/T2+1/T3+1/T4+1/T5+1/T6+1/T7)*98)*T2)-98,-100)
I couldn't see how to slip that into your formula, but the rest is brilliant

Comment: You can try.. you are close anyway.. As long as you can follow the logic.. you can see the pattern here for 'wrapping' formula and the stacked-if formula.. want to have a try ? meet me [here](http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/ikan?password=) (online for 120 minutes) .

Comment: cheers @p-phidot It wasn't the addition of that code that concerned me, more the earlier code with the CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET which concerned me. As the previous 5 were not all the same, I was not entirely sure how to add the 6th one correctly. Above is the new code with the addition of the 6th row in the calculation section, though

Comment: I had also noticed an error on my side... the `INDIRECT("H"&` shouldn't be there it should be something like `OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-3,COLUMN()-1) ..` I 've corrected it..

Comment: Just noticed " As the previous 5 were not all the same" .. you are right.. it is not really the same.. the logic here is.. the concatenate is used to check for blank cells, so if you want to add another one.. just add another term in the concatenate function.. with the change of '-4' in the `IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)-4,COLUMN()-1),"")`  to '-5' (refer the row `(ROW()>6)` line ).  Mind sharing your tries by adding it (editing) to you question post ? –

Comment: cheers @p-phidot Just trying to get my head around it all, so broke down each E2= statement and noticed that for E2=2, it is different length to both 3 + 4 and E2=5 is only (E2=5)), without any CONCATENATE argument to follow.It goes straight into the profit calculation. It just doesn't look right to the eye when I put them one under the other that way. Is that how it is meant to be or should it also do the same as the previous ones? Will add E2=6 as well as the profit calculation and post for you to look at

Comment: I took a screen grab and posted it above of the E=2 and so on statements one under the other

Comment: @p-phidot I updated above and put in E2=6 for you to look at. I put E2=4 just before it, which is copied from the original, so I basically just altered the original to reflect 6 rows.

Comment: You are close, I've add "update 2" in the post. Please don't hesitate to ask if you are stuck in understanding it.

Comment: Apologies @p-phidot Have been swamped with tours this last few days and not a chance to reply. I am excited to have a try and solving it with the information you have given me. I will post as soon as I can, but will probably be after Christmas. cheers

Comment: No worries.. Happy holiday. ( :

Comment: @p-phidot OK, so progress report is that the execution formula looks to be no issue. That seems easy to grasp, but I cannot get my head around the concept of the [CheckEmptyCell]. This is mainly to do with the fact you say it is checking for empty cells in column E and there are NO empty cells in column E anywhere. Each and every cell has a number in it from 1 to 6, so that entire concept just seems alien to me. Are you able to elaborate as to why the formula is looking for empty cells? cheers

Comment: err.. not really what I said/meant.  it is actually checking the cell above the current cell. So let say you are applying the formula in BT10, referring to condition 3 ; it checks if BT9 is empty , then condition 4 ; it checks if BT9  and BT8 is empty, and so on. | It does check column E values (as for `E9 <> E10`,  `E10=2` and so on..) but not for empty cell.

Comment: I had included the full solution & alternative explanation method in update 4. All the best. ( :